# How can I bring a 'sencha' selectfield into view when I am using an overlay?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I currently have a setup where you press a button and an overlay is displayed. 
The overlay looks like follows:

```
this.popup = new Ext.Panel({
    floating: true, modal: true, centered: true, width: 600, height: 400,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            title: 'Custom Search',
            docked: 'top'
        },
        new Ext.field.Select({
            label: 'abc', name: 'asz', options: [...]
        })
    ]
});
```

Now as you can see there is a single selectfield on my overlay, the problem is, when you click to bring up the selection menu, the selection menu appears behind the overlay. I have tried all kinds of hacky tricks to no avail. I have tried adjusting the zIndex values, however they just seem to either not change, or change back to sencha's defaults, because it doesnt seem to make a difference.

I would never have thought that in sencha i could spend so many hours trying to put a selectfield onto an overlay. This problem seems to occur in both chrome & safari (ipad)

Both overlay & selectfield code was basically taken from here http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/

Comment: Are you developing with 1.x or 2.x? Ext.field.Select is only in 2.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are referring to 1.x or 2.x. You use Ext.field.Select which is a 2.x class, but you point to the 1.x examples..

If you are talking about Sencha Touch 2, your code should just work. However I know there was a bug with one of the PRs where it did not work.

I have tested this with Beta 3 and it works as suggested:

```
this.popup = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    floating: true,
    modal: true,
    centered: true,
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            title: 'Custom Search',
            docked: 'top'
        },
        Ext.create('Ext.field.Select', {
            label: 'abc',
            name: 'asz',
            options: [{
                text: 'asd', value: '1'
            }]
        })
    ]
});

Ext.Viewport.add(this.popup);
this.popup.show();
```

If you are talking about Sencha Touch 1, you will have to modify the z-index of the picker. Use Chrome to figure out what the className is (probably `.x-picker`) and set the z-index to something like `999`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't contain enough infomation. But I think you missed something.

`when you set z-index property, you should make sure the overlay is positioned( absolute, relative, fixed).`

You can add position property, and test it again. Maybe it works for you.

Comment: using chrome dev tools, I looked at the most outer containers for both objects and found that the Overlay was positioned relatively (I assumed because it is centered, and the select menu was positioned absolutely.

This problem is quite easy to replicate, just create an overlay as in the kitchensink demo, and append any 'selectfield' onto it, if I can provide more information, feel free to let me know.

Comment: I don't believe jsfiddle has support for Sencha Touch, Also tried Ext.js 3 & 4, didn't seem to work, this is the code, dumbed down: http://jsfiddle.net/SQvaY/